# Error in knitting RMarkdown into work document, possibly due to installed packages

Tags: r, r-markdown

As the title says, I'm attempting to knit an RMarkdown file but I am receiving the error:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source) l trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror Calls: 
<Anonymous>... withvisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted
```

The error is called on line 20 of my rmd file where I have my [install.packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHoTq.png) listed.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("zoo")

library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(gridExtra)
```

I'm not quite sure what this would be, I tried taking the package chunk out to see if it would still read an error, but obviously, it errored out when I used one of the packages in my script.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Remove those lines. There's no need to reinstall packages you have installed each time you knit, and it makes no sense from markdown's standpoint.

Comment: The error suggests that your R script is not sourcing any `.Rprofile` or something that would tell R which mirror to use for installing packages. Pick a mirror and explicitly include it as `install.packages(c("ggplot2", "zoo"), repos="https://...")`, chosen from https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Comment: @Phil, I think there are valid situations where the package needs to be installed each time. As an example, if I use a barebones docker (`rocker`) image, it might need to install some packages each time it is called. While I agree that this may not be the most desirable in the long-term, perhaps it is meant to be a throw-away no-deps rendering.

Comment: @r2evans Fair enough, I can see that.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `installed.packages()` function to determine whether a package needs to be installed during execution of an Rmd script.

For example, we'll check to see whether the `zoo` package is installed and install it if necessary, using the National Institute for Computational Sciences CRAN mirror (as noted by r2evans in the OP comments).

```
installedPackages <- installed.packages()[,1] 
if(!("zoo" %in% installedPackages)) install.packages("zoo",repos="https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/")
library(zoo)
```